# Property '"disabled"' is incompatible with index signature

Tags: angularjs, express, angular-material

ias: "disabled"; required: false; }; disableRipple: { alias: "disableRipple"; required: false; }; color: { alias: "color"; required: false; }; tabIndex: { alias: "tabIndex"; required: false; }; extended: { ...; }; }' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [key: string]: string; }'.

Property '"disabled"' is incompatible with index signature.
Type '{ alias: "disabled"; required: false; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Answer (score 1):

Your ***@angular/material*** version might be greater than the @angular/cli version.
Check your cli version then run;

**npm uninstall @angular/material**

**npm install @angular/material@cli version**